# Create array of dates from starting date in JavaScript and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I have a React component where I have a date string from which I need to generate an array of dates representing the next 11 days excluding the starting date (10/12/2016). Not sure how to achieve this. That's what I've tried so far but the problem is that by simply looping adding 1 for each iteration on the day, it won't generate the correct date when the date range of 11 days spans between two months:

```
addDays = () => {
   const { startDate } = this.props.pageData.parcelDetails.parcelDetails;
   const date = new Date(startDate);
   let datesCollection = []

   for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
     datesCollection.push(`${date.getDate() + i}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`)
   }

   return datesCollection
}
```

The code above generates the following array:

```
[
   "11/12/2016",
   "12/12/2016",
   "13/12/2016",
   "14/12/2016",
   "15/12/2016",
   "16/12/2016",
   "17/12/2016",
   "18/12/2016",
   "19/11/2016",
   "20/12/2016",
   "21/12/2016"
]
```

How do I generate the correct array, with proper dates for each month?

Comment: `date.getMonth()` [uses a 0 based value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth), so January is 0, just add 1 to `date.getMonth()` or if you really want, use a library like `https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/`

Comment: @George Thank you, fixed that and edited the question accordingly. The problem is that by simply looping adding 1 for each iteration on the day, it wont generate the correct date when the date range of 11 days spans between two months

Comment: In that case I suggest using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) where it'll handle that for you

Comment: possible replicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do that:

```
addDays = () => {
  const { startDate } = this.props.pageData.parcelDetails.parcelDetails;
  const date = new Date(startDate);
  let datesCollection = []

  for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
    const newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + i * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    datesCollection.push(`${newDate.getDate()}/${newDate.getMonth() + 1}/${newDate.getFullYear()}`);
  }

  return datesCollection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding 1 day to each loop.

```
var dateuse = new Date();
dateuse.setDate(dateuse.getDate() + 1);
```

or you can try [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

```
var today = moment();
var dateuse = moment(today).add(1, 'days');
```

Comment: The top code block will not work between months, e.g. if the date is `2018/09/30`

Comment: Works for me. dateuse.setDate(dateuse.getDate() - 1); returned Sun Sep 30 2018 10:19:42 GMT-0300

Comment: That's because you're doing `-1`